# Getting text from string between two characters

Tags: c#, string, split

I am trying to pull apart a string and get the text between two "#"'s.  I have found ways to do it in Java and php and I am assuming they are similar in C#, i just jeep failing and pretty sure its PEBKAC.  So I though I would ask.

Example- I want to programatically pull out "filenameid" and "Name" from this string:

'#filenameid#*30day*#Name#.xls'

Comment: Can you show what you've tried.

Comment: You can try this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx :)

Answer (score 6):

Try *splitting*:

```
  String source = "#filenameid#30day#Name#.xls";

  String[] chunks = source
    .Split(new Char[] { '#' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

then take appropriate chunks:

```
  String id = chunks[0];
  String period = chunks[1];
  String name = chunks[2];
```

Comment: It will work the problem is the format for the string won't be the same every time and the words between the "#"'s may be different.  I am trying to figure out how to get which chunks are between "#"'s if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Use capturing groups.

```
@"#([^#]*)#"
```

Get the string you want from group index 1. Note that lookarounds won't work here.

Comment: He wants two strings. Group index 1 will contain "filenameid" only.

Comment: @Petrichor just use the method which will do a global match.

Comment: That returns "#filenameid#".

Answer (score 2):

If your string has same format always you can do the following:

```
string a = "#filenameid#30day#Name#.xls";
string[]split=a.Split('#');
string fileID = split[1];
string name = split[3];
```

Comment: You need to specify `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to the `Split` function for the file id to be at index 0.  Otherwise it's at 1 and name is at 3.

Comment: @juharr or adjust indices

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman I'm pretty sure I mentioned that in my second sentence.

Comment: It will work the problem is the format for the string won't be the same every time and the words between the "#"'s may be different. I am trying to figure out how to get which chunks are between "#"'s if that makes any sense (as above)

Comment: It doesn't matter how many letters you have between #, as it splits the string by # to array. No of # in the string will give you different no of items in array. So if your filenameID and Name are followed in similar pattern by #, then you won't have any problem

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using Regex.

```
void Main()
{
    const string Expression = @"#([^#]*)*#";
    const string TestSample = @"'#filenameid#30day#Name#.xls'";

    Regex regex = new Regex(Expression);

    regex.Matches(TestSample)
         .Cast<Match>()
         .Select(match => match.Captures[0].Value.Replace("#", ""))
         .ToList()
         .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a low-level solution for the problem:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string text = "#filenameid#30day#Name#.xls";

    int frameStart = 0;
    int match = 0;
    // loop on characters
    for(int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++) {
        char c = text[i];
        switch(c) {
            case '#':
                // evaluate frame (text between meshes)
                switch(match) {
                    // match at index 1
                    case 1:
                        Console.Write("filenameid=");
                        Console.WriteLine(text.Substring(frameStart, i - frameStart));
                        break;
                    // match at index 3
                    case 3:
                        Console.Write("name=");
                        Console.WriteLine(text.Substring(frameStart, i - frameStart));
                        break;
                }
                // move to next frame
                frameStart = i + 1;
                match++;
                break;
        }
    }
    // count of matches is match + 1
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: And why do you need manual string splitting? Too much noise for such a simple task.

Comment: It has the best perfomance and flexibility, and demonstrates the text search algorithm

Comment: Asm implementation will be even more flexible and will provide better performance :) sorry for sarcasm, I've understood your point